# Swift: Calculate how much to rotate an SKSpriteNode to have it pointing at a CGPoint

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm making a SpriteKit game in Playgrounds based on shooting space rocks. In the game, there is a gun, which is a SKSpriteNode and I want it to turn to the point that I pass into a function (CGPoint). What I would like to know is how would I calculate how much to turn the gun to face the given point? Thanks in advance!

Comment: check out atan2(y, x) which will give you the angle of a vector <x, y>.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to tell me what the vector <x, y> contains?

Comment: That would be <point x - sprite x, point y - sprite y>. I'm not familiar with swift, so you'd have to look up the exact code for finding those 4 values.

https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2012/10/trig-lesson.png

Comment: Maths (or, more precisely, trigonometry) is your friend...

Comment: What coordinate system is the point in? The scenes? The guns? Is the point associated with a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long ago, after a lot of mind tweaking math and a sleepless night, I came up with this function:

```
func gunAngle(gunPosition: CGPoint, targetPosition: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let deltaX = Float(targetPosition.x - gunPosition.x)
    let deltaY = Float(targetPosition.y - gunPosition.y)
    let pi = CGFloat(M_PI)
    let angle = CGFloat(atan2f(deltaY, deltaX))
    var newAngle = angle

    if angle < (-pi / 2) {
        newAngle += 2 * pi
    }
return newAngle - pi/2  // Subtracting 90 degrees out of the resulting angle, as in SpriteKit 0 degrees faces left, unless you rotate your gun in the sprite accordingly
}
```

I realize this may not be the best method but it works for me. Some math gurus could probably come up with something really brilliant here. I'm not yet any of those.

Thanks to Ray Wenderlich, on his website there is a tutorial on that topic that helped me a lot in putting the foundation of that math.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe，something like

```
func aim(node:SKSpriteNode, point:CGPoint){

    let angle = atan2(point.y - node.position.y, point.x - node.position.x)

    node.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: angle, duration: 0.5))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution (this may not be applicable to you), is to create an SKNode (called `target` perhaps) and then to set up an `SKContraint` so that your `gun` always faces the `target`. You can then move target when required to wherever you want the gun to face and the gun will turn accordingly.

```
let gun = SKNSpritenode...
let target = SKNode...

let orientRange = SKRange(lowerLimit: 0.0, upperLimit: 0.0)
let orientConstraint = SKConstraint.orientToNode(target, offset: orientRange)
gun.constraints = [orientConstraint]
```